# Should Kotlin JUnit5 test classes contain package statements?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, junit5

I'm writing a Kotlin program which according to convention lives in `src/main/kotlin/mypackage/*.kt` with each source file containing `package mypackage`.

I have used the IntelliJ IDEA option to create a test class, `FooBarTest`, which lives in `src/test/kotlin/mypackage/FooBarTest.kt`. So far, so good.

However, to my surprise, `FooBarTest.kt` does *not* contain `package mypackage`. This means the things it tests, would need to be imported explicitly with separate `import` statements.

Is IntelliJ IDEA telling me a surprising truth, that unlike main source files, test source files should not specify a package?

Or is it making a mistake, omitting a package statement that should be there, and I should go ahead and put in the `package mypackage` statement by hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think IDEA's making a mistake -- or at least, being less helpful than it might.

Of course, there's no real *necessity* for test classes to be in the same package as the tested classes.  But in my experience, it makes good sense: they're easier to find, and as you say, it avoids lots of `import` statements.

It also makes the file hierarchy align with the package hierarchy.  Again, while in Kotlin there's no absolute necessity for that, it does make files easier to find and avoid unexpected clashes, and I've not yet found a reason to diverge from that.